# Figure PNG file exported from Jupyter Notebook is empty

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to export a PNG file containing a figure using matplotlib.pyplot in Jupyter Notebook, but it is empty. I have tried running `fig.savefig()` before `data.plot()`, but the exported PNG file is still empty. Please could you help me fix my code.

My code cell in Jupyter Notebook:

```
fig = plt.gcf()
data = pd.read_csv('data/gapminder_gdp_oceania.csv', index_col='country')
data.plot(kind='bar')
fig.savefig('my_figure.png')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fig.savefig()` may not be as well suited as `plt.savefig()` for this particular use case - I might recommend using the latter.

The reason being: if the source for `pandas.DataFrame.plot()` creates a new figure instance instead of using `plt.gcf()` (the documentation does not specify) then `fig.savefig()` won't work if `fig = plt.gcf()` **precedes** `data.plot()`, but `plt.savefig()` will.

Comment: Awesome, I used `plt.savefig()` instead of `fig.savefig()` and the PNG file finally contains the plot. Thanks for your help! Just to clarify though, is the use of local variable fig redundant in my case?